# Postgres Insert elements to array inside user defined type column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

So I'm trying to insert 3 elements inside an array found inside a user defined type which is a column of a table. This is what I have right now:

```
INSERT INTO pais(pais)
VALUES (ROW ('Espanya', ARRAY['Barcelona', 'Madrid', 'Sevilla'])::t_pais);
```

The type looks like this:

```
CREATE TYPE t_pais AS
(
    nom_pais VARCHAR(35),
    localitzacions t_localitzacio ARRAY
);
```

The t_localitzacio type looks like this:

```
create type t_localitzacio as
(
    nom_localitzacio varchar(35)
);
```

And the table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Pais
(
    id_pais serial PRIMARY KEY,
    pais t_pais
);
```

And i'm getting the following error:

```
malformed record literal: <<Barcelona>>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you simplify the t_pais type like this :

```
CREATE TYPE t_pais AS
(
    nom_pais VARCHAR(35),
    localitzacions VARCHAR(35)[]
);
```

then your insert will work.

If you can't change the table and types definition, then you have to change your `INSERT` statement as follow :

```
INSERT INTO pais(pais)
VALUES (ROW ('Espanya', ARRAY[ROW('Barcelona') :: t_localitzacio , ROW('Madrid') :: t_localitzacio , ROW('Sevilla') :: t_localitzacio ])::t_pais);
```

Comment: Can't do that because I need to leave both tables and types as they are